# IFTTT Webhooks - Not receiving email (but the response says that it was sent)

Tags: webhooks, ifttt

I'm following this tutorial to send email in App Inventor: https://www.hackster.io/taifun/trigger-ifttt-to-send-an-email-using-app-inventor-9df505 (You will have to scroll down on the page to view the tutorial)

The tutorial is straight forward and easy to understand. However, the IFTTT service (Maker) is now called "Webhooks".

I don't know what else has changed since that tutorial was written.
Following the tutorial:

- the URL is correct `https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/Sendmail/with/key/*MYKEY*`
- the RequestHeaders are correct `Content-Type: application/json`
- the PostText is correct: `{ "value1" : "faeryofiris@gmail.com", "value2" : "test", "value3" : "test body" }`

I have double and triple checked for spelling errors.
Once I click a button to send this email, I receive the response:
"Congratulations! You've fired the Sendmail event!"

Except... there is no email. Both emails are my actual emails, so they are valid emails. "faeryofiris@gmail.com" should be the "FROM" email, and "pixiibomb@gmail.com" is the email that is registered on IFTTT (this should be the email that receives a message from faeryofiris) I keep refreshing my gmail, and still... no email.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Could you find a workaround? 
I am thinking about contacting the support.

Comment: Ok I could solve my issue. The thing was that the event (in your case "Sendmail") did not fit the event string I defined in IFTTT (even though there was only one). Maybe you could  check that?

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this issue several times. The solution has always been to click `"Edit Connection"` on the [Webhooks Service Settings](https://ifttt.com/services/maker_webhooks/settings) page. This will get you a new key. It doesn't solve their issue which is that keys tend to die for no explained reason but it should get your setup working again.